# Return first x results from each group, where group x count is not the same, SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The first table has the domain and the count.

```
  domain    count
 abc.com    5
 def.com    10
 ghi.com    11
 jkl.com    4
```

The 2nd table has email id,domain id and domain name (this table would be much longer)

```
 email_id   domain_id   domain
 226902     2443        abc.com
 154689     100945      abc.com
  96480     130702      def.com
 586924     71563       def.com
 142857     132667      jkl.com
3820065     130702      jkl.com
```

What I would like to get is to take the count from the first table and the get the corresponding matches from the 2nd. For example abc.com I would only want the first 5 matches of the email ID from the 2nd table, then def.com, I would only want the first 10 matches of the email ID from the 2nd table and so on...

Is there a way I can do this in SQL or should I move on to do this in say php

Any help or alternative solutions are welcomed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it

```
SELECT *
FROM   first_table A
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (COUNT) *
                    FROM   second_table B
                    WHERE  A.domain = B.domain
                    ORDER  BY email_id,
                              domain_id) CS
```

This will be faster when you have proper `index` on `second_table`. Does not require full table scan like `row_number` method.

If you don't have index on second table then create the following `nonclustered index`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_Second_table_domain_email_id_domain_id
  ON Second_table(domain, email_id, domain_id)
```

Which should help the optimiser to go for `index seek` in `second_table` rather going for table scan

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, also will try this one